# PyDOS Version 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, console

**This is a follow up to the questions: [PyDOS shell simulation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83790/pydos-shell-simulation) and [PyDOS: Version 2.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85866/pydos-version-2-0)**

***Introducing PyDOS 3.0! With brand new features and improved code, this will blow your mind!***

New Features (This list will be updated with PyWrite soon)

- Dialogs are now in a window like design.
- New start-screen, easier to use.
- Create your own name and change it!
- New Commands Dictionary
- `PyCALC` is now called `SimpleCalc`

If you have any ideas for improvements, don't hesitate to post them!

Source Code:

```
#PyDOS Version 3.0 - Written by Mrfunny744
import time
import os
import sys
import random

def ChangeName():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print ("----------------------------------------------")
    name  = input ("Type in your new username: ")
    print()
    print ("This can be changed again if you wish.")
    print ("----------------------------------------------")
    time.sleep(2.5)


def shutdown():
    print ("------------------------")
    print ("|                      |")
    print ("| Thank you for using  |")
    print ("|        PyDOS         |")
    print ("|                      |")
    print ("|                      |")
    print ("|                      |")
    print ("|   Shutting Down...   |")
    print ("|                      |")
    print ("------------------------")
    sys.exit(0)

def end():
    print ("------------------------------------")
    print ("|                                  |")
    print ("|   Thanks for using SimpleCalc!   |")
    print ("|                                  |")
    print ("------------------------------------")
    time.sleep(2)

def calc_a():
    print ("----------------------------------")
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print ("----------------------------------")
    answer = num1+num2
    print ("Your answer is:" ,answer)
    print ("----------------------------------")
    time.sleep(3)
    end()



def calc_m():
    print ("----------------------------------")
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print ("----------------------------------")
    answer = num1*num2
    print ("Your answer is:" ,answer)
    print ("----------------------------------")
    time.sleep(3)
    end()


def calc_s():
    print ("----------------------------------")
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print ("----------------------------------")
    answer = num1-num2
    print ("Your answer is:" ,answer)
    print ("----------------------------------")
    time.sleep(3)
    end()

def calc_d():
    print ("----------------------------------")
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print ("----------------------------------")
    answer = num1/num2
    print ("Your answer is:" ,answer)
    print ("----------------------------------")
    time.sleep(3)
    end()



def simplecalc():
    print ("--------------------------")
    print ("|                        |")
    print ("| Welcome to SimpleCalc  |")
    print ("|                        |")
    print ("| A = Add                |")
    print ("| M = Multiply           |")
    print ("| S = Subtract           |")
    print ("| D = Divide             |")
    print ("| Q = Quit               |")
    print ("|                        |")
    print ("--------------------------")
    print ("|                        |")
    choice = input ("| Choice:                |")
    print ("|                        |")
    print ("--------------------------")
    if choice == 'a':
        calc_a()
    elif choice == 'm':
        calc_m()
    elif choice == 's':
        calc_s()
    elif choice == 'd':
        calc_d()
    elif choice == 'q':
        end()
    else:
        print ("Invalid specifacation.")


def error_message():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print ("----------------------")
    print ("|      Whoops!       |")
    print ("|                    |")
    print ("|                    |")
    print ("|   It dosent look   |")
    print ("|    like the app    |")
    print ("|      exists.       |")
    print ("|                    |")
    print ("|Check and try again.|")
    print ("----------------------")
    time.sleep(3)


os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
print ("---------------------------")
print ("|                         |")
print ("|                         |")
print ("|    Welcome to PyDOS!    |")
print ("|                         |")
print ("|                         |")
print ("|                         |")
print ("|                         |")
print ("|                         |")
print ("|      Version 3.0        |")
print ("|     Alpha Edition       |")
print ("|                         |")
print ("|                         |")
print ("---------------------------")
time.sleep(3)
print ()
print ("-----------------------------------------------")
name = input ("Enter a name: ")
print ("-----------------------------------------------")
print ("Information has been saved.")
print ()
print ("This data will be used in some applications.")
print ("-----------------------------------------------")
time.sleep(3)
while True:
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print ("-------------------------")
    print ("|                       |")
    print ("|                       |")
    print ("|     Loading Home      |")
    print ("|        Screen         |")
    print ("|                       |")
    print ("|                       |")
    print ("|                       |")
    print ("|                       |")
    print ("|                       |")
    print ("-------------------------")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print ("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print ("| Username:",name,"                                                           |")
    print ("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print ("|                                                                             |")
    print ("|               PyDOS Home Screen - Type in an app below.                     |")
    print ("|                                                                             |")
    print ("|       Apps:                                                                 |")
    print ("|                                                                             |")
    print ("|       ChangeName                                                            |")
    print ("|       Shutdown                                                              |")
    print ("|       SimpleCalc                                                            |")
    print ("|       PyWrite                                                               |")
    print ("|       About                                                                 |")
    print ("|                                                                             |")
    print ("|                                                                             |")
    print ("|                                                                             |")
    print ("|   PyDOS Version 3.0 Alpha (Alpha 1.2                                        |")
    print ("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    selection = input("Select An App: ")
    command_actions = {
    'ChangeName' : ChangeName,
    'SimpleCalc' : simplecalc,
    'Shutdown' : shutdown
    }
    if selection in command_actions:
        action = command_actions[selection]
        action()
    else:
        error_message()
```

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: I still don't understand why you think the `sleep` is necessary at all. It objectively makes for a worse user experience.

Comment: That's a whole boatload of print statements. Why not have a `echo()` function that accepts a list instead, and each element of that list is a line to print? Something like this: https://gist.github.com/jsanc623/ad1319b4a5bf6db34469 but that also handles padding and alignment, so you don't have to pass in padding.

Comment: The reason why there is `sleep` is because I am moving away from the 'DOS' thing now. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> time.sleep(2.5)
> ```

Again, don't `sleep` your program, it makes it unnecessarily slow, and it doesn't even act like an old machine would because when it does run, it runs quite fast.

---

> ```
> --------------------------
> |                        |
> | Welcome to SimpleCalc  |
> |                        |
> | A = Add                |
> | M = Multiply           |
> | S = Subtract           |
> | D = Divide             |
> | Q = Quit               |
> |                        |
> --------------------------
> ```

You prompt for a capital "A", but only accept a lowercase "a":

> ```
> if choice == 'a':
>     calc_a()
> ```

You can easily change this to accept both like this:

```
choice = input ("| Choice:                |").lower()
```

If you want to accept any input that starts with an "A" or "a", just append `[0]` to the line.

Your various `calc_x()` functions are extremely similar.  You can reduce some of that similarity by either passing them an argument or using a function to input the values.  Personally, if you are not going to accept entire equations and handle order of operations, I would use one function:

```
def calc(operation):
    print ("----------------------------------")
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print ("----------------------------------")

    if operation == 'a':
        answer = num1 + num2
    elif operation == 's':
        answer = num1 - num2
    elif operation == 'm':
        answer = num1 * num2
    elif operation == 'd':
        answer = num1 / num2

    print ("Your answer is:" ,answer)
    print ("----------------------------------")
    end()
```

Then, call this function from `simplecalc` like this:

```
if choice in "asmd":
    calc(choice)
else:
    print ("Invalid specifacation.")    // "specification"
```

---

Don't call `end()`, or any other functions, from your `calc()` function.  Actually, you shouldn't even print from your `calc()` function - what if you want to calculate something and not print it?  Also, inputting values is not part of the calculation.  I would write this like this (extraneous output removed for simplicity):

```
def calc(operation, num1, num2):
    if operation == 'a':
        return num1 + num2
    elif operation == 's':
        return num1 - num2
    elif operation == 'm':
        return num1 * num2
    elif operation == 'd':
        if num2 == 0:
            raise ValueError('Divide by 0 expection')

        return num1 / num2
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unknown error')

def simplecalc():
    print ("Welcome to SimpleCalc! You have the following operators:")
    print ("A: Add")
    print ("S: Subtract")
    print ("M: Multiply")
    print ("D: Divide")
    print ("Q: Quit")

    choice = input ("Choice: ").lower()[0]

    if choice == 'q':
        end_simple_calc()
        return

    if choice not in "asmd":
        print ("Invalid specification.")
        end_simple_calc()
        return

    try:
        num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        print ("Your answer is:", calc(choice, num1, num2))

    except ValueError as err:
        print(err.args)

    end_simple_calc()
```

This not only catches the invalid division by 0 operation, it also catches when you input an invalid number and prints an error message instead of the printing stack trace and crashing.

---

Right here, you only allow three apps; why are the other two in the prompt list?

```
command_actions = {
'ChangeName' : ChangeName,
'SimpleCalc' : simplecalc,
'Shutdown' : shutdown
}
```

---

You should be consistent in your naming:

> ```
> def ChangeName():
> def shutdown():
> ```

I believe the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) standard states you should use `snake_case` names.

Also related to naming: `def end()`.  What does `end()` do?  It prints a conclusion to `SimpleCalc`, but does not show that in the name.  What if I was looking through your code adding a new feature, and I saw that in `SimpleCalc`?  I might add it to the end of my new feature and have a problem.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the functions for `SimpleCalc` should be put in their own module or their own class - presumably you'll want to add more commands at some point, and a function called `end` is a bit generic as a name.

Your naming conventions in general could be improved - instead of `calc_d`, call it divide, for instance.

For the `SimpleCalc` main function, consider adding a loop until the user selects quit, so they can do more than one calculation.

Instead of having a static list of available commands, maybe loop through the keys of your `command_actions` dictionary.